# MessageBox error shows up 6 times because of my collection length, but i want it to show up 1 one time everytime the user write the wrong login

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication

there is a  MessageBox error shows up 6 times because of my collection length, but i want it to show up  one   time everytime the user write the wrong login to a maximum of 3 attempts.
     Im using C# for a WPF and the list is in a Txtfile thank you.
     that's the code im using: like so

```
 private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {     
        string utilisateur = txtUtilisateur.Text;
        string motPasse = pswdBox.Password;


        //Recuperation des valeurs saisies par l'utilisateur en lettre minuscule.
        //On verifie si les valeurs saisies sont vides ou des valeurs nulles.
        //S'il y a des valeus dans les txtbox
        bool test = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < client.Personne.Count; i++)
        {
            {
                if (utilisateur == client.Personne[0].Nom && motPasse == client.Personne[0].Password)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Bienvenue: {utilisateur}");
                    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;//Masquer le formulaire du login
                    BANQUE ZoneAdmin = new BANQUE();//Consructeur de la fenetre WPF
                    ZoneAdmin.ShowDialog();//Montrer la fenetre...
                    this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                }
                else if (utilisateur == client.Personne[i].ID && motPasse == client.Personne[i].Password)
                {
                    // On affiche un message de bienvenue a l'utilisateur.
                    MessageBox.Show($"Bienvenue: {client.Personne[i].Nom}.", "Bienvenue",
                        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    //On met fin a l'application 
                    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;//Masquer le formulaire du login
                    Banques ZoneClient = new Banques();//Consructeur de la fenetre WPF
                    ZoneClient.ShowDialog();//Montrer la fenetre...
                    this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;//Reafficher le formulaire du login apres la fermeture du formulaire du SGI



                }

                //Il faut revenir la dessus si le nip est erroner sa ne marche pas...
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Accès Refuser, veuillez reessayer, " + attempts + "  tentative(s) sur trois");

                    txtUtilisateur.Clear();
                    pswdBox.Clear();
                    attempts+=1;
                    if (attempts == 4)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Vous avez exceder le nombre de tentatives permis; veuillez reessayer plus tard");
                        this.Close();
                       }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The last line is of the question is part of the code

Comment: In practice you are going to track failed login attempts in the Backend Database. It is more reliable and you can do extra stuff like warning the user of failed attempts (with times) on next login. | You are using `client.Personne.Count` for the loop itterations, but we have no data on what either of those return and thus how often this loop runs. | Are you checking the password per character? Why would you ever do that?

Comment: thank you Christopher for getting back at me that quick, That is exactly the problem I don't want it to do that I want it to inform the user once and then the user has 2 more trials. but instead its showing up 6 times in one shot, wich is the length of my collection.

Comment: I repeat: **Why** do you do this inside that for loop, if you do not want to repeat it X times? You went out of your way to have this code run 6 times. What type is Personne? What is in that collection?

Comment: if I try to do it out of the loop I get errors saying that I can't start with an else theres more details about person:

Comment: public class Personnes
    {
        private string nom;
        private string id;
        private string password;
        private ObservableCollection<Personnes> personne;

Comment: its a collection inside a TXTfile

Comment: Ok Christopher let me know if I take it out of the loop what would be my code?

Comment: "if I try to do it out of the loop I get errors saying that I can't start with an else" Why would you start any code section with a Oprhaned else??? Sorry, but I think you need to go back to learning basic programm flow. | There is also a huge question if the whole collection is even properly read.

Comment: yes the collection is properly read if you enter the right password and the right Id it will log you in the only issue I have now is that im trying to give the right for the user to make one mistake please response with respect. I am aware of everything your saying . I tried taking it out of the loop and put a break;. It didn't work. Now the situation here is that an admin has a username and a password. The Client has a username and password as well bringing him in a different window. Now I need to know how can I write it down without the dialogresult showing up 6 times